# list index out of range when list has not been exceeded

Tags: python, list

### does anyone know why I get list index out of range for this code?  The len() is 380 but  it stops printing after 10.  Thanks

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import json

team_id = ['ARS','BOU','BHA','BUR','CHE','CRY','EVE','HUD','LEI','LIV','MCI','MUN','NEW','SOU','STK','SWA','TOT','WAT','WBA','WHU']

i=0
while i <= len(fixture)-1: 
    try:
        htmlfixture = urlopen("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/fixtures/" + str(i)).read()
        fixture = json.loads(htmlfixture)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
    except URLError as e:
        print("the server could not be found!")
    else:    
        print(fixture[i])
        print(type(fixture))
        fixture = fixture[i]
        id = fixture['id']
        team_a = team_id[fixture['team_a']]
        print(team_a)
        team_h = team_id[fixture['team_h']]
        print(team_h)
    i = i+1
```

Comment: I don't recognize the language but are you sure you can do fixture = fixture[i] and  id = fixture['id']. It seems you are accesing an array first with an int and then with a string.

Comment: To me it seems you're overwriting fixture all the time. Is the last fixture a dictionary with 11 elements? That would do it.

Comment: @Juan - this is python with exception handling :) fixture = fixture[i] digs out a dictionary from a list and fixture['id'] accesses it's member/key called 'id'. All looks well besides the overwriting.